# angular2 use external javascript file

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-canvas

I want to place my online game that I made that with pure javascript and html5 canvas in my angular2 project.
I wrote my scripts in external file and add the script tag in the head on angular `index.html` and in my component's typescript I declared my onload function like this:

```
declare var startGame1: any;
```

the startGame1 is a method that make the canvas ready for my game.
the problem is when I call `startGame1()` in `AfterViewInit` I get errors like this:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'clearRect' of undefined ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
ViewWrappedError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'clearRect' of undefined at ViewWrappedErro……} Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'clearRect' of undefined
```

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: yes I do @Giovane

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to load the external js using the `.angular-cli.json`.

In the `apps -> scripts` and insert the relative path of your external `.js` in the array.

And inside the `app` folder, create a `.d.ts` file to insert your `declare var startGame1: any;`. For example:

myGame.d.ts

```
declare var startGame1: any;
```

The `myGame.d.ts` will be loaded automatically by the webpack and then define your `startGame1` for your app.